# How to display number of posts from a tag by id?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying

```
<?php
$number = 'apartamenty';

$terms = get_terms('post_tag', "number=$number");
if($terms){
foreach ($terms as $t){
    echo $t->name.' : '.$t->count;
}
}?>
```

But this code show two tags...

Comment: Question: The value in `$number` appears to be the actual term, i.e. post tag.  Is this correct?  Are you wanting to get number of posts that are attached to the post tag `apartamenty`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of posts that are attached to a specific post tag, such as `apartamenty`, you would use [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).  This WordPress Core construct lets you grab the `WP_Term` object for the specific post tag.  In your case, you are wanting the post tag of `apartamenty`.

Okay, you'd have a function (i.e. to make it reusable) that runs this code and you'd pass in the actual post tag that you want to explore.  This function is using the post tag slug.

```
function render_post_tag_post_count( $post_tag ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $post_tag, 'post_tag' );
    if ( ! $term ) {
        return;
    }

    // You get back an WP_Term object
    // You can then use $term->count, which gives you the
    // number of posts attached to this post tag.

    echo (int) $term->count;
}
```

The property `$term->count` gives you the number of posts that are attached to that term.

You use it like this:

```
render_post_tag_post_count( 'apartamenty' );
```

### What if I want to get it by post tag ID?

Take the above code and change the first argument from `slug` to `id`.  Then you would pass the post tag's ID instead of its slug.

You can learn more about the [parameters in WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Parameters).